# $(window).height() doesn't seem exact

Tags: jquery, css, height

http://jsfiddle.net/WL5nr/1/

I have a div whose height is larger than the screen and I'm trying to eliminate the scrollbar and have it still fill the page (whatever size the page is). I set `overflow: hidden` and then set the `$(window).height()` but I'm still seeing a scroll bar.

Doing `$(window).height() - 20` eliminates it but it doesn't seem like I should have to do that. And so maybe `- 20` works in the jsfiddle.net window...  what if the window is bigger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The window height does not take into account the margin that is by default applied to the body. If you eliminate this margin you should get the effect you want:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't take into account the body's margin. See http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/Hmw7M/

```
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```