# making div height by height of window minus all other div heights

Tags: jquery, css, height

This question is a follow up to [$(window).height() doesn't seem exact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15469572/window-height-doesnt-seem-exact)

First, my js fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/WL5nr/3/

So I have a div 4800px tall and then another div 20px tall. I want the 4800px tall div to fill the window after all other divs have shown up.

I guess I could do a for loop to find all divs or p's or whatever it needs to find, get all of their heights and subtract them from `$(window).height()`, but I'm not sure how to do that let alone if that's the best method.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? You can't simply post question after question here until you have a working product... This is for when you're stuck, not lazy.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick, it's self explanatory:

http://jsfiddle.net/3Qrry/

```
var demoheight = $(window).height() - $('div#extradiv').height();
$("#demo").css("height", demoheight);
```

For all the extra `div`s add a `- $(element).height()` to the `demoheight` variable.